# Add button for every item in a list to open specific item Version History popup for

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, version-history

could you help please, is it possible to add button for all items in a list to open their version history pop-up? This button or link should be on the specific column field for every items.
Is there opportunity to do it ootb or using spfx extension?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the version history that comes with SharePoint can be viewed through the three dots on the right side of the stand-alone item and by selecting version history in the drop-down menu. As long as you enable version control.

[image]